# IP Subnetting vs VLAN for VoIP Traffic

Tags: vlan, subnet, voip

I have a fairly small network with scanners, printers, phones and workstations/servers all sharing the same subnet (10.0.0.0). I am having issues with our VoIP phones and sluggish response on the network when scanning large files.

I would like to separate my VoIP traffic from all other network traffic. Would I be better served to create a VLAN or just simply program the VoIP router and phones to a different subnet?

The VLAN option seems more complicated and would require a different subnet anyway (at least that's my understanding of the VLAN) so would it not be easier to just create a new subnet (10.0.3.0) program my phone router to that subnet and assign static IP's to my phones (in the 10.0.3.0 subnet) using the router as the gateway?

Comment: `I would like to separate my VoIP traffic from all other network traffic` - That's a poor way to troubleshoot the problem. Assuming that's the cause of the problem and then undertaking a network redesign based on that assumption isn't the best way to go about resolving the problem. At any rate, Physically segregating the traffic would necessitate creating VLAN's.

Comment: And yours is a poor answer, but thank you anyway. If your going to take the time to tell me what I am doing "wrong" then at least offer some "right" suggestions. The subnet worked fine, no more VoIP problems and after further research, I have found that VLAN's are not the defacto answer for all problems.

Comment: Mine wasn't an answer, it was a comment. If you're going to take the time to snipe at someone for giving you honest feedback at least take the time to be correct.